# Microchip bending the rules of C?

Tags: c, struct, standards, typedef, pic

I was digging through some headder files relating to  a PIC microcontroller when I came accross a load of structs that look like this:

```
typedef struct tagPORTDBITS {
  unsigned RD0:1;
  unsigned RD1:1;
  unsigned RD2:1;
  unsigned RD3:1;
  unsigned RD4:1;
  unsigned RD5:1;
  unsigned RD6:1;
  unsigned RD7:1;
  unsigned RD8:1;
  unsigned RD9:1;
  unsigned RD10:1;
  unsigned RD11:1;
  unsigned RD12:1;
  unsigned RD13:1;
  unsigned RD14:1;
  unsigned RD15:1;
} PORTDBITS;
```

Is this standard C? I cant find any other referances to anything that looks like this, i.e. with the ":1" after the variable definition

I assume all the elements are representing bits, so is this a Microchip addition to their C compiler to make things easier for embeded programmers?

Comment: Nope, that's pretty much standard. Google for ["bit field"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field)

Comment: Just for reference, it is in section 6.9 of K&R C 2nd edition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a C [bitfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field), which is a perfectly valid (although unportable) construct.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yszfawxh.aspx) or [here](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/bitfields.html) for more info.

Although the data layout in a bitfield is implementation-defined and therefore unportable, they are often used in embedded processing to map individual bits of a register to logical names.  This works because most embedded processors use their own specific toolchain where the bitfield layout rules are well understood.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is standard C. The name for this is [bit fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field).

Answer (score 3):

This is standard C. It is called a [bit-field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field)

This struct definition is commonly used for exactly what you provided as example: Making bitwise data communication more easy to read, because you can then access single bits easily with a name instead of shifting or bitwise operations and struggling around with bytes, while still having the ability to use the data directly as a single integer or byte.